# Como retornar função corretamente? (Escopo de Variaveis)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Tenho a seguinte função que realiza uma requisição a uma API utilizando o Angular e gostaria que a função retorna-se os dados, mas estou com problemas de escopo de variáveis:

```
var buscarVagasPorEndereco = function(){
    var enderecosVagas = [];
    $http.get("dados.json").then(function(response){
        enderecosVagas = response.data.enderecosVagas;              
    });
    return enderecosVagas;
};
```

Comment: O `$http.get` realiza uma requisição assincrona. Em uma resposta bem crua, seu return será executado antes de receber uma resposta do servidor, então você estará retornando um array vazio.

Comment: Sim, mas teria alguma forma de corrigir?

Comment: Onde queres usar esse valor? podes mostrar mais código?

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas precisamos ver onde você está utilizando essa função. Como o @Sergio falou, tente mostrar um pouco mais do seu código.

Comment: @dukehplay você não pode ' corrigir' a natureza assíncrona da linguagem. Eu também perdi muito tempo no início tentando fazer minhas aplicações se comportarem em fluxos síncronos. Se me permite dar uma dica, aceite e use este fato a seu favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `$http` do Angular (e o ajax em geral) é assíncrono. Isso quer dizer que essa função dá retorno antes de o ajax ser feito e por isso `undefined`.

O que podes fazer é retornar a promise e usar o encadeamento `.then` para chamar o código que precisa dessa resposta.

Por exemplo:

```
var buscarVagasPorEndereco = function(){
    return $http.get("dados.json").then(function(response){
        return response.data.enderecosVagas;              
    });
};
```

E depois podes fazer:

```
buscarVagasPorEndereco().then(function(enderecosVagas){
    // fazer algo aqui com enderecosVagas
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar o return dentro da função get:

```
var buscarVagasPorEndereco = function(){
    var enderecosVagas = [];
    $http.get("dados.json").then(function(response){
        enderecosVagas = response.data.enderecosVagas;   

        return enderecosVagas;
    });
};
```

Comment: Qual é a diferênça de ter o return dentro da função get?

Comment: Não funcionou :(